# Using Hamachi VPN to connect to Linux VM at home

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I have a CentOS 5.10 Linux box at home running on VMWare, with Windows 2008 as the host. I have set up a Hamachi VPN so that I can connect to the Host server from work, I attempted to add a second VNIC to the VM and bridged it to the hamachi Network Interface. I spun up the VM and checked eth1 with ifconfig and its throwing me a ipv6 address not a ipv4. I want to hook this VM up so that I can run a ssh command from work to the VM. MY network at home is all on Local 198.168.***.*** hence the need to make a VPN network like Hamachi. I cannot seem to find anything that tells me or helps me with tunneling my Linux VM via Hamachi.

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your ethernet settings in VMWare machine in NAT mode, so it can obtain a IP address from your local DHCP server or assign it a IP address manually. Open up a port in your router to the IP address your VMWare Machine has.

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/network_nat_details_ws.html

By the way, in this way you don't even need a Hamachi connection :)